# Is C# 7 working in VS 15 Preview 4?

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

I tried a simple test but it didn't like out variables

As a simple test, I wrote this (perhaps there is something simple wrong with it, but I also had trouble with patterns and with tuples)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{

    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Runner runner = new ConsoleApplication2.Runner();
            Point p = new ConsoleApplication2.Point();
            runner.PrintCoordinates(p);
        }
    }


    public class Point
    {
        int x = 20;
        int y = 50;
        public void GetCoordinates(out int a, out int b)
        {
            a = x;
            b = y;
        }
    }

    public class Runner
    {
        public void PrintCoordinates(Point p)
        {
            p.GetCoordinates(out int x, out int y);
            Console.WriteLine($"({x}, {y})");       // x does not exist in current context
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0), where the `PrintCoordinates` example method comes from:

> Note: In Preview 4, the scope rules are more restrictive: Out variables are scoped to the statement they are declared in. Thus, the above example will not work until a later release.

The new tuples suffer from a similar problem, though it seems you can partially work around that with a NuGet download:

> Note: Tuples rely on a set of underlying types, that aren’t included in Preview 4. To make the feature work, you can easily get them via NuGet:
>
> - Right-click the project in the Solution Explorer and select “Manage NuGet Packages…”
> - Select the “Browse” tab, check “Include prerelease” and select “nuget.org” as the “Package source”
> - Search for “System.ValueTuple” and install it.

Comment: Yep, I discovered this in [Try Roslyn](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:features-outvar/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbGNmfYsmANwHswAExgBZABQBKZq3ayeVAE4cYAXhgRUAdxgAFARGSScs2bgB0AcVTJ6fPgsGQqaEGL7BkMSJ4AeAGhh3T28YBAljEzZbCBA+IlQzAHUFMDQAGUhUMQASACImHwBfAKYEQtzwmTZCqo5CEnJKGjo9b1qWSLYQn1UYACYABgjIkIRegFYh2tN67n4hGCsbOwcnFzcPLwMYKgCgrc8CCWn2Ds7ZKl6fYfOYAl6EG9ka5+xCoA==) as well. Focus is on `if` statements and similar currently I think.

Comment: I'm assuming you could clone the master repo and build it yourself though as the current head does seem to support this syntax.

Comment: @DavidG: Indeed. For the more conservative, there's always waiting it out :)